# How to a open a file in vim using pipe

Tags: linux, bash, vim, pipe, locate

I get to use the `locate` command extremely often.

So if I run the following command.

```
locate updatedb | head -1
```

Then it gives me the `O/p`

```
/usr/updatedb.conf
```

I wonder if there is any such command that can let me open that file directly?

I am hoping for something like this.

```
locate updatedb | head -1 | vim
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're nearly done:

```
$ locate updatedb | head -1 | xargs vim
```

sometimes (under certain terminals) you need reset the terminal after editing.

```
$ reset
```

Comment: Most probably your version of `locate` have `-l` / `--limit` / `-n` option so you do not need `head -1`: `locate -n 1 updatedb | xargs vim`

Comment: Why does this terminal corruption happen? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: @JacobodeVera, See also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76526479/how-not-to-mess-terminal-up-after-sys-stdin-read-and-subprocess-invoking-vim

Answer (score 23):

As an interactive editor, Vim needs both stdin and stdout, so using it within a pipe is problematic and makes Vim warn about this. For just a single file, process substitution solves this easily:

```
vim "$(locate updatedb | head -1)"
```

You can also use backticks, and that even works inside Vim itself:

```
:edit `locate updatedb | head -1`
```

Comment: This also works on strings with spaces, which is nice for file names like "version 2 - final.csv".

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [the above answer](https://superuser.com/a/769394/943615), to avoid the "terminal corruption" stated by Jacobo de Vera in the comment, use the xargs option `-o` or `--open-tty` to make vim assume the input is from a terminal, not stdin.

```
$ locate updatedb | head -1 | xargs -o vim
```

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44428/307359

Answer (score 0):

I know this is bad solution but I used this for creating alias in .bashrc:

```
locate updatedb  > /tmp/vimForTempDontTouch && vim /tmp/vimForTempDontTouch
```

Downsides: 
   ugly

Advantage: 
  No side effects with terminal

Answer (score 0):

This is what old good standard [vipe](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is used for.

FYI, I wrote [pyvipe](https://github.com/Constantin1489/pyvipe/blob/master/pyvipe/pyvipe.py)(python port of it) for my research. The linked github code is truly short like the original vipe.

Turns out it is related to file descriptors and `dup()` and `dup2()`.